# Tailwind CSS Styles Not Applied in React App After Scraping Next.js Page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, content-management-system, html-parsing

I have a Next.js application (version 13) containing several components styled using Tailwind CSS. These components are then scraped from a CMS system written in React with Node.js and sanitized with `cheerio`. Post scraping, the resulting HTML content is sent to the React frontend and parsed using the `html-react-parser` library.

However, I am facing an issue: some Tailwind CSS styles are not applied in the React app, even though the CSS classes are retained intact. This inconsistency is evident when comparing the display of the same page in both the Next.js app and the React CMS.

**1. Next.js Components:**

```
// Catalog component
<section className='...'>
  {cars.data?.map((car: Car) => (
    <CarComponent key={car._id + ''} car={car} />
  ))}
</section>

// Car component
<div className='...' onClick={() => router.push(`${pathname}/${car._id}`)}>
  <DetailsComponent car={car} />
</div>

// Details component
<div className='...'>
  // Image and details here...
</div>
```

**2. Scraping:**

```
pageByUrl: async (_, { code }) => {
  // Scraping and sanitizing logic here...
  const html = await scrapeContent('http://localhost:3000' + url);
  const page = sanitizeHTML(html);
  return { page };
}
```

**3. React Frontend Parsing:**

```
const EditableMain: FC = () => {
  // Parsing and rendering logic...
  const parsed = parse(page as string, options);
  return <>{html}</>;
};
```

**4. Expected vs. Reality:**
I expected the page to look identical in both the Next.js app and the React CMS, given that the classes remain the same. However, certain Tailwind CSS styles are missing in the React CMS version.

**5. Supporting Evidence:**
I will provide two screenshots for comparison: one from the Next.js application and one from the React CMS. This will showcase the discrepancies in styling.

[Next.js App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYTo1.jpg)

[React CMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUJ2B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
The main challenge arose from the EditableMain component where dynamically parsed HTML wasn't getting recognized by Tailwind CSS:

```js
const EditableMain: FC = () => {
  // ... 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (page) {
      const parsed = parse(page as string, options);
      setHtml(parsed as any);
    }
  }, [page]);

  return <>{html}</>;
};
```

*Key Points:*

1. Tailwind CSS might not recognize or scan HTML dynamically rendered within JSX.
2. As a workaround, I integrated components from the Next.js app directly into my React application, and the styles applied correctly.
3. Post-refresh, the parsed HTML then appeared styled correctly, likely due to the styles being cached.

**Conclusion:**
Tailwind does not readily apply styles to dynamically introduced classes that haven't been rendered by React. Ensure all necessary Tailwind classes are rendered (even if hidden) to be recognized and preserved during the build phase.